# Using a ParseKit grammar to parse timestamps

Tags: objective-c, timestamp, parsekit

I've a fairly simple question about ParseKit and parsing timestamps... how do I go about forcing the symbolic-nature of a dot/period.

For example, if I am trying to parse `2008-01-25`, I could use something like `date = /\d{4}/ '-' /\d{2}/ '-' /\d{2}/`.  In fact, there is a `date.grammar` shipped with ParseKit that does exactly this (interestingly enough, though, the provided grammar doesn't work in the DemoApp unless you add `@symbolState='-';`, but I digress...)

However, what do I do if I want to parse a date with dots in it... for example, `2008.01.25` or `2008-01-25-12.34.45`.  I've tried added `'.'` to the `@symbolState` directive but it just keeps getting ignored.  Note that I am relying on the DemoApp to test my grammars at the moment... not sure if that makes any difference.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried: /\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  That doesn't work though, but then again, `/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/` doesn't parse either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developer of [ParseKit](http://parsekit.com) here.

First, thanks for the heads up on the bug in the `date.grammar` file. I have fixed it.

---

As for your main question, I'm pretty sure what you are trying was not possible with ParseKit until now.

That is, ParseKit's tokenizer (`PKTokenizer`) was not able to produce **only** whole number `Number` tokens. Numbers were always tokenized as floating point which means it was impossible to parse input like `3.14` as three separate tokens `3` (Number) `.` (Symbol) `14` (Number). Rather it would always be tokenized as `3.14`.

Good news: I've added this capability with a new method:

```
-[PKNumberState allowsFloatingPoint]
```

which defaults to `YES`.

And I added a matching **Tokenizer Directive** which you can use in your ParseKit Grammars like:

```
@allowsFloatingPoint = NO;
```

**NOTE** you'll need to checkout the latest HEAD of trunk on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/parsekit/) to see this feature.

So, here's an example date grammar which does roughly what you were asking for with the new feature:

```
@symbolState = '.';
@allowsFloatingPoint = NO;

@start  = date;

date    = year dot month dot day;

year    = /\d{4}/;
month   = /\d{2}/;
day     = /\d{2}/;

dot    = '.';
```

---

Comment: Thank you.  That now works.  For those playing along at home, my grammar for a timestamp (`2008-01-23-12.34.56.987654`) looks like:

`@symbolState = '.' '-';

@allowsFloatingPoint = NO;

@start  = date;
date    = year dash month dash day dash hour dot minute dot second dot nanos;

year    = /\d{4}/;
month   = /\d{2}/;
day     = /\d{2}/;
hour    = /\d{2}/;
minute  = /\d{2}/;
second  = /\d{2}/;
nanos   = /\d{6}/;

dot    = '.';
dash   = '-';`

Comment: BTW, Google Code *just* started cooperating again, so I have now fully checked in this feature. Sorry for the delay/confusion.

Comment: Todd - just wondering if Parsekit can be used to parse and process stuff like "Meeting day after tomorrow in London at 3pm"? Essentially I'd like to extract the date and time and create an alert based on this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering if a simpler idea might be to get parseKit to simply parse the date as a string, and then hand it off to the NSDate::dateWithNaturalLanguageString:locale: orNSDate::dateWithNaturalLanguageString: for processing.

Comment: With the grammar I have (see above), I am wondering if this is indeed a better approach.  The problem with setting '.' as a symbol and disallowing floating points means that I will have a lot more trouble parsing `2008-01-23-12.34.56.987654 value=3.14`.  

What would be nice is if the directives could be applied to specific production.

Comment: @Todd will have to answer that. I have only a basic knowledge of ParseKit and grammars :-(

Comment: I'm interested in exactly this too, as parsing a date is my next ParseKit challenge and (for a complete solution) I'll also need to handle various localised date formats.